# spring-data-mongodb. How can i dynamically create a database in mongo using spring-data-mongodb library?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

spring-data-mongodb. How can i dynamically create a database in mongo using spring-data-mongodb library?

I am trying to use Spring-Mongodb-Data module for CRUD operations against Mongo database and going through examples and articles my assumption is that databasename should be pre-defined in spring context xml when defining MongoTemplate bean.

In my case I have an multi-tenant application that will accept requests over http and my application should create the mongodatabase on-the-fly and use the name provided in the input http request to create the database and then load the data into collection in the newly created database.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to dynamically populate the databasename in MongoTemplate or MongoRepository without having to provide it in spring context.xml?

Please help me.

Thanks
-RK

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following instead of going through the pre-defined spring context configuration.

```
MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate(Mongo mongo, String database) {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongo, database);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Chermosillo.

Comment: Thanks for reply Chermosillo. 
Yes that's how I am creating MongoTemplate bypassing bean definition in spring context.xml but wasnt sure if thats correct approach or not.
Can you tell if there is anything I should be concerned about with creating MongoTemplate in my Service class using Mongo bean and then cache the MongoTemplate in a Map (databasename-mongotemplate) which is later accessed for CRUD operations.

Comment: I guess the only concern I would have is how many instances a user will have and I would try to keep it one template per user session if possible, meaning a single user will have access to it's own database but you don't need to cache the others